# Lync multiple sign in with virtual desktop, missing notifications

Tags: virtual-machine, lync

We use Lync for company communications and I've recently been switched to working via a virtual desktop (VMWare).

I'm now having issues where new message / conversation notifications are only being displayed on my laptop (running the VMWare client software), not on the virtual machine I connect to for my work.

This means I loose new conversations behind my remote desktop, and I have to alt-tab back to my laptop to respond to people, even though Lync works fine when I initiate a conversation from my VDI.

I would simply sign out from Lync on my laptop all togehter, but we use it for VOIP communications which are tied into the company phone network and it's not possible to pass the USB headsets we use through to the Virtual Machine.

I know that Lync support multiple sign on locations, and I've read that new conversations are supposed to appear at ALL signed on locations. However, what I'm seeing is that notifications NEVER appear on my VDI, unless I first sign out from my laptop.

Has anyone see this behavior, does anyone know of a fix?

Comment: This sounds like an issue that needs to be handled by your IT department.  Are you one of them?

Comment: Very likely I'm the very first person to encounter this. I'm a programmer, so supported by our IT department, and VDI's and Lync voice calling are both new to our setup. Hence I wondered if there was some way of designating a particular Lync client as the "currently active" one. I don't think this is possible, and certainly it's not really in keeping with the ethos of transparent / smart multiple sign on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my problem. Notifications were not missing but rather:

- Notifications appeared on both machines simultaneously
- Due to identical placement of my task bar and system tray, notifications appear in the exact same screen location for both machines.
- "Local" notifications on my laptop appear in front of those on the remote client.

So, the local notifications were completely obscuring the remote ones and making them impossible to click. My workaround is to move the start bar on my remote machine to my 2nd monitor, then the notifications appear separate.